# CakePHP Auth inside routes.php, bad practice?

Tags: cakephp

I'm attempting to do this: (pseudo code)

```
if(USER IS LOGGED IN){
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'films', 'action' => 'index'));
} else {
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'));
}
```

Which simply redirects them to their 'dashboard' if they are logged in or asks them to register if they aren't signed up!

Is this bad practice to have this IF statement inside the routes.php of CakePHP?

Comment: This could also lead to issues with Router::url or HtmlHelper::link since they can parse your routes to determine how to create links.

Comment: I would use the app_controller to do this check... or you can extend your pages_controller.php and do the same thing in the index action.

Answer (score 1):

it is likely to create problems because the session usually gets initiated later.
why not switching the action / view inside a so called "OverviewController" like I do?

```
if (UID) {
    $this->_actionOne();
} else {
    $this->_actionTwo();
}
```

which then call their own view:

```
$this->render('some_view');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. and although @mark pointed reasons from cake's view, the reason is because you are mixing modules functions.
When someone gets to the films/index and you want him to register first, you are redirecting him from the films controller. so, simply add a redirect or, a link for registration.

If you still want it to do it automatically, you probably should create a router_controller (bad idea).
The cake solution is to stay in the films controller, and in the index function..
But, in the view, don't show the default output, but some kind of "register" element..